# ASP.NET using Knockout.js and mappings

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using the following code i experience a strange problem. When I click and call showVacationModal data is retrieved fine from the server and result is displayed correctly. If i keep clicking the same person(id) it continues to work.

If I click a different person (eg. different id) with no vacations nothing is showed = OK.

### The problem

Now when I click the first person again nothing is displayed. (data is retrieved fine in ajax call).

Any ideas?

### My JS code:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
        this.vacations = ko.mapping.fromJS(null);
    };

    var model = new ViewModel();


    function showVacationModal(id) {
        var model = {};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetVacations",
            data: "{personId: '" + id + "'}",
            delay: 1,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {

                model.vacations = ko.mapping.fromJS(msg.d);
                ko.applyBindings(model);


                $('#vacationModal').modal('show')
            }
        });

    }
```

### My HTML:

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            First name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Last name
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: vacations">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: Id">
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="text: PersonId">
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="text: Begin">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Can you show a simplified working version using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something more like this?

```
function showVacationModal(id) {
    // var model = {}; no need to reset the model property
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetVacations",
        data: { personId: id }, // why wrap data in strings?
        delay: 1,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            //model.vacations = ko.mapping.fromJS(msg.d);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(msg.d, {}, model.vacations);
            // ko.applyBindings(model); no need to reapply bindings

            $('#vacationModal').modal('show')
        }
    });
}
```

See [this ko.mapping documentation section](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#specifying_the_update_target) for more information.

Comment: You hit on it in your code: I think the real problem is reissuing the bindings.

Comment: @JoelCochran yes, the `ko.mapping.fromJS` always returned something funky when I tried it. Passing in a 2nd and 3rd parameter always did the trick for me.